# Recursive function to determine the needed operations in order to reach a given result

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a little problem that I can't seem to wrap my head around at the moment.
Could anyone help?

Basically it sounds like this :

Write a recursive function that determines all combinations of operators (+ and -) that can be pun between integers from 1 to N>=2 so that the result of the expression is a given number X. If there is no combinations then print "N/A".

Example for input:

```
6
3
```

The output should be:

```
1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 5 + 6 = 3
1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 = 3
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 = 3
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow! Why can't you seem to wrap your head arount this problem? What approaches have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Here is a hint that might help: forget about "long" sums with more than two terms. Remember that you are allowed to use parentheses. Imagine that +, -, *, / all take at most **two** operands. `1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 5 + 6` really is `((((1 + 2) + 3) - 4) - 5) + 6`. This might help with a recursive approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This console app sample will solve your problem :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int result = Search(2, 6, 1, 3);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static int Search(int start, int end, int current, int searched)
        {
            if (start > end)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(current == searched);
            }

            return Search(start + 1, end, current + start, searched) + Search(start + 1, end, current - start, searched);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use numbers from 1 to N, the first time you start with 1 and from there on you will be able to either add or subtract, so:

```
private void addSubtract(int N, int current, int sum, int expected) {
    if (current <= N) { //We still have items to add/subtract
        values[current - 1] = sum + current; //First we try adding the item
        addSubtract(N, current + 1 , sum + current, expected); //we call the method recursively, keep N as it was, increment current, add current to sum and pass expected
        if (current > 1) { //1 is always positive, so we only try negative for subsequent elements
            values[current - 1] = sum - current; //we store the value
            addSubtract(N, current + 1, sum - current, expected); //we call the method recursively, keep N as it was, increment current, subtract current from sum and pass expected
        }
    } else { //We reached to the end of the line
        if (sum == expected) { //It's a solution
            //Do something with values, because this is a solution
        }
    }
}
```

I have used a helper array called values, so at the end of your algorithm, if the sum happen to be expected, then we just use `values` for whatever purpose we want.

You can call it as

```
addSubtract(6, 1, 0, 3);
```